# How to read a DFA for digit summation that uses carry bits?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I'm looking to understand how can one graph the following DFA given its mathematical definition.

Take for example this (from [1], p. 107):

- **Set of States**: $Q = \{q_{\langle carry=0\rangle}, q_{\langle carry=1 \rangle}\}$
- **Alphabet**: $\Sigma = \{\langle x_{i}, y_{i}\rangle \mid x_{i},y_{i}\in[0..9] \}$
- **Start State**: $s = q_{\langle carry=0\rangle}$
- **Transition Function**: $\delta(q_{\langle carry=c\rangle}, \langle x_{i}, y_{i}\rangle) = \langle q_{\langle carry=c'\rangle}, z_{i}\rangle$ where $c'$ is the high order digit of $x_{i} + y_{i} + c$ and $z_{i}$ is the low order digit.

How does one read the required no. of states and the edges with their symbols?

**References**

1. J. Edmonds, *How to Think About Algorithms*, Cambridge University Press, 2008.

Comment: Have you looked at what the parts of the mathematical definition mean? To be blunt, the question you're asking is extremely simple, the answer is written in the example, so it's difficult to determine where you're having a problem. On another note, please avoid using images where possible, it makes the question harder to search and reduces their ability to attract readers and answers.

Comment: I'm troubled by how the DFA selects "high-order" and "low-order" digits. Or is it merely an operation "of an edge", which is not explicitly defined "how it does it", but just that it should do it, was it implemented.

Comment: Are you asking how to read mathematics?

Comment: If you can get your hands on Peter Linz's *Formal Languages and Automata*, this problem appears at the end of Chapter 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not really in the implementation of the DFA, but in understanding what the DFA is doing. With those who have access to the text, careful reading of the algorithm preceding it should give a deal of understanding.

From the perspective of the DFA, it has two states, as listed in the **Set of States**, the symbols on the transitions are pairs of numbers, i.e. each "symbol" is written as five characters (for our understanding, we could encode them any sensible way we wanted of course).

The tuple as the right hand side of the transition function is unusual (and as far as I can seem undefined in the text). What is actually represented here is a [finite state transducer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_transducer), which are essentially equivalent to a DFA, but get to produce a symbol of output at each transition. So the $z_{i}$ is what gets written to the *output tape* that normally doesn't exist. It also doesn't have an accept state, as the output is no longer yes or no, but whatever is written on the tape.

Now, to understand the construction in full, we need to understand what it's trying to do - add two decimal numbers. It does this digit by digit (from right to left). At each individual addition (digits $x_{i}$ and $y_{i}$), there might be a carry digit, which needs to be remembered for the next addition.

When two decimal digits are added, there are only two possible carries: $0$ or $1$. If we already have a carry, this is still true (the limit cases are $x_{i} = y_{i} = c = 0$ and $x_{i} = y_{i} = 9$, $c = 1$). To put this another way, the output of adding two decimal digits and a carry bit is a two digit number $c' z_{i}$, where $c'$ is the carry bit for the next addition and $z_{i}$ is the decimal output digit.

To give an example of the result, here's the transducer for the binary case. Each transition gives the two input digits, the output digit and target state of the transition. Remember that each transition implicitly includes the carry bit in the addition:

[image: Transducer for single digit binary addition with carry.]

Comment: The confusing part was the usage of and reference to + and being able to output a solution, when it's not really visible in the DFA. I'm also still not sure whether they talk about the binary representation of digits 1, ..., 9.

Answer (score 0):

$Q$ is the set of states.  Therefore, the number of states is exactly the cardinality of $Q$, i.e., $|Q|$.

Each transition corresponds to an edge.  If $\delta(q,x)=q'$, then there is an edge from state $q$ to state $q'$ on input symbol $x$, so you draw an arrow from $q$ to $q'$ and label it with $x$.